# Fabric: "We are building your audience insights. Please update to the latest version of Crashlytics Kit.."

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I'm using Fabric/Crashlytics with my Android app. The audience section keeps telling me to update to the latest version of Crashlytics. I've done that. It still keeps telling me to update. How do I fix this?

[image]

According to the documentation, the latest Crashlytics version is 2.8.0.
https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install

That's what I'm using:

```
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Comment: whats the @aar for? try removing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. You can see this error also if there isn't enough information to populate Audience Insights while also protecting user's privacy. There is a minimum threshold of users (which I can't share) that need to overlap between your app and Twitter in order for us to populate the data.

Comment: Thank you for the response directly from Fabric. My app has over 700 monthly users. Both Firebase and Google Analytics show the audience information for the same app.

Comment: Of course, happy to help. Just to clarify, the key component is the overlap between your app's users who are also Twitter users.